# Is 2 a zero divisor in the finite field $\mathbb Z_2$?

Tags: field-theory, modular-arithmetic

Zero divisor is defined as an element $a\not = 0$ of a ring $R$ if $\exists b\not = 0$ such that $ab=0$ or $ba=0$. Now consider $\mathbb Z_2$. All multiplies of two are zero such that $0=2=4=6=2n=0 \mod 2$. So

**Is 2 a zero divisor in $\mathbb Z_2$?**

Comment: No. $2$ is actually equal to $0$ in that field.

Comment: Fields do not contain zero divisors, and $2 \equiv 0$ as said above.

Comment: $2$ is an integer, so $2\notin\mathbb{Z}_2$; sometimes (or even often, it's not important) an integer is used to represent the corresponding multiple of the ring's identity. Under this convention, $2$ and $0$ represent the same element.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip I find it hard to think that all multiplies of two are equal to zero even though we can write them as $2=4=6=\ldots=2n\forall n\in\mathbb Z$ where visually they are not written as $0$. If multiplies of two are considered as zero divisors, then the order of the field is infinite while if 2 is not considered as zero divisor, then the order of the field is zero.

Comment: @hhh All $2k \in \mathbb Z$ are equivalent to 0 by the very definition of the quotient ring $\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because $2=0$. Formally, the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ are cosets of natural numbers. The symbols $2$ and $0$ refer to to the same coset, $\{0,2,4,\ldots\}$. This is just like that $\frac{2}{3}$ and $\frac{4}{6}$ are different symbols that refer to the same number.

Since $2=0$, $2$ is not a zero divisor because zero divisors are defined to be non-zero

Comment: So the $a\not = 0$ in the question about the definition of zero divisor actually means that $a$ does not belong to the coset with zero? It does not mean that *"such thah a is not equal to zero"*? How would you formulate the definition of zero divisor more explicitly?

Comment: @hhh $a \neq 0$ refers to $0 \in \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$ not $0 \in \mathbb Z$. They're not the same thing.

Comment: It means that $a=\=0$ based on whatever $a=b$ means in this context. In this setting, equality means "representative of the same coset"

Comment: Does this mean more generally that $\mathbb Z_n$ for some $n\in\mathbb Z_+$ has no zero divisor? Wondering now the implications on field characteristics...thinking. +1 for differentiating cosets and modular arithmetics, still puzzled...thinking.

Comment: If $n$ is prime, then yes, it's a field. In Z_6, $2$ and $3$ are zero divisors. $2=\{..., -4,2,8,...\}$ and $3=\{..., -3,3,9,...\}$

Comment: What about more simple exapmple $\mathbb Z_4$? Is 2 zero divisor there? In thinking $\mathbb Z_n$, do you think first equivalance classes, cosets or things in modular arithmetics? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes it is. Any divisor of $n$ other than $\pm 1$ and $\pm n$ is a zero divisor of $Z_n$

Answer (score 0):

$$\mathbb{Z}_{2}=\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z}$$ is a set of equivalence classes, so when we write $n = 0 \in \mathbb{Z_{2}}$, what we mean is *"$n$ is equivalent to $0$ under the equivalence relation $\sim$, where $a \sim b \iff 2|(a-b)$"*, but it is the *equivalence class* that lives inside $\mathbb Z_{2}$, and there are two of them. Since $2$ is equivalent to $0$, their equivalence class is the same, so $2=0$, which cannot be a zero divisor.

Comment: Do you mean that $\mathbb Z_2$ does not mean $Z_2$ in modular arithmetics (I may have totally wrong understanding about modular arithmetics)? What does $\mathbb Z_n =\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ really mean? And when do you use $\mathbb Z_2$ instead of $Z_2$ (I may have fixed mistakenly your answer)? Does this mean that equivalence classes cannot have zero divisors? Or does this mean that $0$ corresponds to zero divisors, coset of zero divisors or coset of elements? Does any of $\mathbb Z_n, n\in\mathbb Z$ have zero divisors? Now confused on $a\not = 0$, thinking...

Comment: $\mathbb{Z_{2}}$ is exactly the same as $\mathbb{Z_{2}}$ in modular arithmetic. In ordinary $\mathbb{Z}$, by $0$ we mean "the element $0$ of $\mathbb{Z}$". In $\mathbb{Z_{2}}$, by $0$ we mean "the set of all the elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ divisible by $2$". Moreover, since we have theorems like "the sum of two odd numbers is even" etc, we can define an arithmetic on these equivalence classes (modular arithemtic).

Comment: That is, when we write $n \in \mathbb{Z_{2}}$, we're really using $n$ (an integer) as a *representative* for the equivalence class of $n$. So if I write $1$, I'm talking about all the integers that leave remainder $1$ when divided by $2$. If I write $17$, I'm talking about the set of integers that leave the same remainder when divided by $2$ as $17$ does. But $17$ has remainder $1$ when divided by $2$. So $1$ and $17$ form the same equivalence class under the equivalence relation "remainder mod 2". That is, in $\mathbb{Z_{2}}$, $1=17$ (and similarly for any other odd number).

Comment: Whether you use $Z$ or $\mathbb{Z}$ doesn't matter. And yes, $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ can have zero divisors - consider the case $n=4$. We have $2\cdot 2=0$, if $n=4k+2$ and $m=4l+2$, $nm=4(4kl+2k+2l+1)$ (i.e. $nm$ is divisible by $4$).