# $\mathbb Z_2$ has no zero divisors while $\mathbb Z_6$ has zero divisors?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Zero divisor is defined as an element $a\not = 0$ of a ring $R$ if $\exists b\not = 0$ such that $ab=0$ or $ba=0$.

Now, $2$ is not a zero divisor of $\mathbb Z_2$ since it is equivalent to the coset $0$, more [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1664443/is-2-a-zero-divisor-in-the-finite-field-mathbb-z-2). But $2$ is a zero divisor of $\mathbb Z_6$ but I cannot understand why.

Please demonstrate why $\mathbb Z_6$ has zero divisors while $\mathbb Z_2$ does not have zero divisors: I cannot fully understand the notation $a\not = 0$ to mean coset and by this question I am trying to understand it better.

**How can you intuitively demonstrate that $\mathbb Z_2$ has no zero divisors while $\mathbb Z_6$ has zero divisors 2 and 3?**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A zero divisor is a number that is not otherwise zero, but multiplies by another number that is also not zero and the result is zero.  $2\cdot 3=6\equiv 0\pmod 6$, but $1\cdot 1=1\equiv 1\pmod 2$ and $1$ is the only non-zero class in $\Bbb Z_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only two elements in $\Bbb{Z}_2$, $[0]$ and $[1]$. As you said, in $\Bbb{Z}_2$, $[2]=[0]$, so by definition it is not a zero divisor. The only other option is $[1]$. But $[1]\cdot[1]$ is not $[0]$, and we can't use $[1]\cdot[0]=[0]$ according to the definition, so $\Bbb{Z}_2$ has no zero divisors.

However, in $\Bbb{Z}_6$, we have $[2]\cdot[3]=[6]=[0]$, so both $[2]$ and $[3]$ are zero divisors.

The best intuitive explanation I have is that $\Bbb{Z}_2$ and $\Bbb{Z}_6$ are completely different groups. In particular, $[2]$ in $\Bbb{Z}_2$ is NOT the sam as $[2]$ in $\Bbb{Z}_6$. In the first case, $[2]=\{\ldots, -2, 0, 2, 4,\ldots\}$. In the second, $[2]=\{\ldots-4, 2, 8, 14\ldots\}$. That we use the same notation for both may be a source of confusion.

---

Here, $[a]$ indicates an equivalence class. In $\Bbb{Z}_n$, $[a]=\{a+kn:k\in\Bbb{Z}\}$. If some of this is new to you, I recommend you do a quick google search of modular arithmetic.

Comment: Thank you for writing out cosets +1, I had mistakenly thought cosets to refer to multiplies. Can you explain why 4 is not a zero divisor in $\mathbb Z_6$? Namely $3*4=12=0$ where $3\not = 0$ and $4\not = 0$.

Comment: Right; $[2]$, $[3]$, and $[4]$ are the zero divisors of $\Bbb{Z}_6$.

Answer (score 0):

Within modular arithmetic, $\forall a \in \mathbb Z_n , \forall b \in \mathbb I$ an = 0

Substituting *n* for 0 in in the original definition, we get that *a* is a zero divisor when *ab*=*n* or *ba*=*n*.

This is true if and only if *a* is a factor of *n*.

Looking at the factorization of 2, {2}, one can intuit that 2 is the only zero divisor in $\mathbb Z_2$.

Likewise, the factorization of 6, {2,3,6}, reveals that in addition to 6, 2 and 3 also serve as zero divisors in $\mathbb Z_6$.

(Note: We exclude 1 from the factorization).